# Python exe не работает

Tags: python, json, api, exe

Всем привет , скомпилировал python в exe и выдает ошибку :

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1499, in open_local_file
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'C:\\Users\\YARUSKI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI134482\\swagger_spec_validator\\schemas\\v2.0\\schema.json'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 36, in wrapper
  File "swagger_spec_validator\validator20.py", line 195, in validate_json
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 63, in read_resource_file
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 57, in read_file
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 67, in read_url
  File "urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
  File "urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1477, in file_open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1516, in open_local_file
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'C:\\Users\\YARUSKI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI134482\\swagger_spec_validator\\schemas\\v2.0\\schema.json'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BTC.py", line 76, in <module>
  File "telebot\__init__.py", line 480, in polling
  File "telebot\__init__.py", line 539, in __threaded_polling
  File "telebot\__init__.py", line 502, in __threaded_polling
  File "telebot\util.py", line 117, in raise_exceptions
  File "telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
  File "BTC.py", line 42, in inlin
  File "bitmex.py", line 35, in bitmex
  File "bravado\client.py", line 109, in from_url
  File "bravado\client.py", line 135, in from_spec
  File "bravado_core\spec.py", line 348, in from_dict
  File "bravado_core\spec.py", line 360, in build
  File "bravado_core\spec.py", line 353, in _validate_spec
  File "swagger_spec_validator\validator20.py", line 159, in validate_spec
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 38, in wrapper
  File "six.py", line 702, in reraise
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 36, in wrapper
  File "swagger_spec_validator\validator20.py", line 195, in validate_json
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 63, in read_resource_file
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 57, in read_file
  File "swagger_spec_validator\common.py", line 67, in read_url
  File "urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
  File "urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 534, in _open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1477, in file_open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1516, in open_local_file
swagger_spec_validator.common.SwaggerValidationError: ("<urlopen error [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\YARUSKI\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\_MEI134482\\\\swagger_spec_validator\\\\schemas\\\\v2.0\\\\schema.json'>", URLError(FileNotFoundError(2, 'Системе не удается найти указанный путь')))
[3848] Failed to execute script BTC
```

Вот код:

```html
from binance.client import Client
import time
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlencode
import bitmex
import telebot
from telebot import types
from time import sleep
import re
######################################################
a=0
BASE_URL = 'https://api.binance.com'
PATH = '/api/v3/depth'
headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': 'тут ключ , вам его не надо знать'
}
client = Client('тут ключ , вам его не надо знать', 'тут ключ , вам его не надо знать')
params = {
    'symbol': 'BTCUSDT',
    'limit': 5

}
bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут ключ , вам его не надо знать');
bitmex_api_key = 'тут ключ , вам его не надо знать'  
bitmex_api_secret = 'тут ключ , вам его не надо знать'

####################################################
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def start_message(message):
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Проверка бирж",callback_data="1")
    key.add(but_1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать',reply_markup=key)
#######################################################
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def inlin(c):
    if c.data == '1':
        while a<1:
            client1 = bitmex.bitmex(api_key = bitmex_api_key , api_secret = bitmex_api_secret)
            result = client1.Quote.Quote_get(symbol="XBTUSD", reverse=True).result()
            url = urljoin(BASE_URL, PATH)
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
            str1 = r.json()
            bids = ''
            asks = ''
            for i in str1:
                if str(i) == 'bids':
                    bids = ' '.join([str(item) for item in str1[i]])
                if str(i) == 'asks':
                    asks = ' '.join([str(item) for item in str1[i]])
            bids = re.findall(r'\d*\.\d+|\d+', str(bids))
            asks =re.findall(r'\d*\.\d+|\d+', str(asks))
            naib_for_asks = 12.1
            naim_for_bids = 12000000.0
            for i in bids:
                if float(i)<naim_for_bids and float(i)>120.0:
                    naim_for_bids = float(i)
            for i in asks:
                if float(i)>naib_for_asks:
                    naib_for_asks = float(i)
            bid_mex = int(result[0][0]['bidPrice'])
            ask_mex = int(result[0][0]['askPrice'])
            razn_mex_bit = abs((float(naim_for_bids)/float(ask_mex))-1) * 100
            vivod = 'Биржа           Покупка            Продажа' + '\n' + str(toFixed(razn_mex_bit, 2))+'%           BTC/USDT         XBTUSD' + '\n' + 'Binance         '+str(naim_for_bids)+'            '+str(naib_for_asks)+'\n'+'Bitmex           '+str(bid_mex)+'                '+str(ask_mex)
            try:
                bot.edit_message_text(str(vivod),c.message.chat.id,c.message.id)
            except:
                bot.edit_message_text(str(vivod)+'',c.message.chat.id,c.message.id)

            sleep(5) 
def toFixed(numObj, digits=0):
    return f"{numObj:.{digits}f}"
bot.polling()
```

Comment: напиши как конвертировал в exe

Comment: pyinstaller --onefile BTC.py

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить параметров `--add-data "путь1:путь2"` где путь1 будет чтото вроде `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\swagger_spec_validator\schemas` а путь2 - `swagger_spec_validator\schemas`

Comment: Пишет что не удается найти указанный файл . У меня эта либа хранится по такому пути: G:\Python Projects\Lib\site-packages\swagger_spec_validator\schemas . Но не ищет все равно

Comment: Надо почитать доки. В зип файлы закинулись?

Comment: Да , все есть .